# Is it possible to define a partial schema Python-eve?

Tags: python, eve

I have some pretty big, multi level,  documents with LOTS of fields (over 1500 fields). While I want to save the whole document in mongo, Ido not want to define the whole schema. Only a handful of fields are important. I also need to index those "important" fields. Is this something that can be done?

Thank you

Comment: Is possible add fields as you want remember that ```mongodb``` is schema-less that mean you don't need to make a schema to insert data, just insert them with ```db.example.insert({here your fields that you want insert}) ```

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind... found it... (ALLOW_UNKNOWN)